# Count how many times a value appears in sql query using php

Tags: php, sql

I have created a database and website that will be used by football managers to select their team etc. Once a match has been completed events will be stored in the     `match_players` table. Such events are Goal, Yellow Card, Red Card etc. I have no problem getting this information into php from SQL db.

I need to add up how many times a Goal appears (a '1' is placed in the SQL table) and for what team so that a final score can be displayed. So, for example, if Team A has 1 goal and Team B has 2 then I need to display that. I am trying to count the amount of times that a Goal is registered in the table. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MYSQL `SUM`

```
select SUM(Goal) from match_players where Team="A"
```

Or you can get the same for all teams by

```
select Team,SUM(Goal) from match_players group by Team
```

Comment: Not forgetting the GROUP BY

Comment: I would also suggest a date constraint, otherwise the Goals will add up from every game the team plays

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you demand this sum to SQL directly?

```
SELECT SUM(goals)
FROM match_table
WHERE team = 'Barcellona'
```

This should be much faster also than elaborate all data at "php-level"

If you want this detail for all teams

```
SELECT team,SUM(goals)
FROM match_table
GROUP BY team
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you store a 1 each time a goal is scored, your table looks like this:

```
TeamID  goal
   1     1
   2     1
   1     1
   3     1
   2     1
   2     1
   1     1
```

So you just want a count of how many times a team appears in that table:

```
select TeamID, count(*) from table group by TeamID
```

Will give you

```
 TeamID | count(*)
     1  |  3
     2  |  3
     3  |  1
```